# Возможно ли отправить сообщение пользователю когда он "лайкнет" страницу?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Например есть официальная страница некой Компании на facebook. Делается рассылка всем пользователям этой компании (интернет-магазина) зайти на официальную страничку на фейсбук и  присоединится то есть "Лайкнуть". После "лайка" нужно отправить код пользователю. код будет выступать для скидки....  Возможно ли вообще такое сделать?

Comment: Флаг вам в руки! Ломайте Facebook!  =)

Comment: да вроде API есть, но все на english....

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду `Facebook Pages`, а внутрь `pages` засунуть приложение, то можно отследить лайкнул ли юзер это приложение и на основании этого показывать другой контент.
Чтобы постить что-то юзеру на страницу необходимо получить `permissions` от пользователя, т.е. ему по любому прийдется авторизироватся.